# Why does creating a do-nothing sub class change a Blazor component's behavior?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I think it's well worth reading both Brian's and MrC's answers to this question below.

---

I want to add some minor processing to `DxGrid.OnInitializedAsync()`. So, to start, I created a do-nothing subclass as follows:

ExDxGrid.razor:

```
@inherits DxGrid
```

ExDxGrid.razor.cs

```
public partial class ExDxGrid : DxGrid
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

I then changed `<DxGrid> ... </DxGrid>` to `<ExDxGrid> ... </ExDxGrid>`. I don't know what specifically it is unhappy about, but it now displays no data in the grid. So it looks like somehow this impacted assigning a list to `DxGrid.Data`.

How can this have any impact? Shouldn't it by definition have no impact?

I'm not asking this question specifically for DxGrid. I'm asking in terms of the general case. How can a do-nothing subclass have any impact?

Comment: Hi David. If you want this to work remove the ExDxGrid.razor which is invoking the razor compiler creating a new override for the `BuildRenderTree`. Keep the `ExDxGrid.razor.cs` I would suggest renaming it to just `ExDxGrid.cs`

Comment: @BrianParker I take it that is because the .cs file is a subclass. But the .razor is not a subclass, it's a replacement rendering object. Is that right? And a file Anything.razor is fundamentally the class Anything and therefore all that's truly needed to subclass is a .cs file that inherits from it. Is that correct? This all makes sense - but I didn't see it. Thank you.

Comment: The razor compiler takes the `.razor` and generates a partial class of the same name. This is why code behind files have to be partial. Specifically it overrides the `BuildRenderTree` method of `ComponentBase`. BTW as you are not using the razor compiler your `ExDxGrid` doesnt not have to be partial. Also remember `RenderFragments` are delegates.

Comment: @BrianParker If you write all that as an answer, happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can a do-nothing subclass have any impact?

You created a new `.razor` file. Which has no output.

The razor compiler takes the `.razor` markup sections and creates a partial class of the same name.
This is why code behind files have to be partial. Specifically, it overrides the [`BuildRenderTree` method of `ComponentBase`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components/ComponentBase.cs,48). In your case you effectivly replaced the `DxGrid`'s `RenderFragment` with your own (blank).

Remember [RenderFragments are delegates](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components/RenderFragment.cs,13)

To avoid the razor compiler being invoked and creating a new override just create a normal `.cs` file using inheritance.

`ExDxGrid.cs`

```cs
public class ExDxGrid : DxGrid { }
```

This will still be recognized as a component as it ultimately implements `IComponent` through inheritance.

Whilst some go further to show how to combine outputs with using a new `.razor` I find this over complicating and easier to do with normal component composition. Doing this you can only add markup around the base components output so why make your component more complicated?

Answer (score 3):

modify your ExDxGrid.razor to :

```
@inherits DxGrid
@{
    // Display the base DxGrid that we are inheriting from.
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}

@code {
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
   
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a helpful answer. But I think @BrianParker comments above are better - just don't create the .razor part.

Answer (score 1):

This answer provides a bit more background to @BrianParker's.

So everyone can use the code [Not everyone will have DxGrid]  here's our basic component:

```cs
//Hello.razor
<h3>Hello Blazor</h3>
```

When you create a Razor file like this:

```cs
//Child.razor
@inherits Hello
```

It outputs a blank area, not "Hello Blazor".

If we look at the code output by the Razor Compiler we see:

```cs
public partial class Hello : ComponentBase
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    {
        __builder.AddMarkupContent(0, "<h3>Hello Blazor</h3>");
    }
}
```

```cs
public partial class HelloChild : Hello
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    {
    }
}
```

Even though there's no content in `HelloChild`, the Razor compiler built out a `BuildRenderTree` override method.

An interesting point.  This class satisfies the requirements for the Razor Compiler.

```cs
public abstract class RazorBase
{
    protected abstract void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder);
}
```

And:

```cs
//Hello.razor
@inherits RazorBase
<h3>Hello Blazor</h3>
```

Will compile to this:

```cs
    public partial class Hello : RazorBase
    {
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
        {
            __builder.AddMarkupContent(0, "<h3>Hello Blazor</h3>");
        }
    }
```

You can't use it as a component, and don't have access to all the `ComponentBase` methods, but it's a valid class!  And demonstrates all the Razor compiler is interested in is finding a `BuildRenderTree` to override [with or without content]!

If you code a straight class, without a `BuildRenderTree`, the base class `BuildRenderTree` will be called.

```cs
public class HelloChildClass : Hello
{
    // Don't do this
    //protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    //{
    //}
}
```

Finally we can do something like this in a Razor component, which calls the base `BuildRenderTree` and shows the "Hello Blazor".

```cs
@inherits Hello
@Content

@code {
    public RenderFragment Content => (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
}
```

If you want to see the code generated by the Razor compiler, here's my *note to self* - https://gist.github.com/ShaunCurtis/0a487f4d0970267f871bea5ef77e4e42